# How to get the size/coordinates of the content area of Container objects?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I get the size of the content area of Container objects? One non generic solution is checking for styles I suppose but I am looking for some code that works generic for all standard flex Container objects.

Edit: The controls are Flex 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean other than simply doing container.width and container.height?

Edit from comment :

Ah ok.

Container has a mx_internal variable called contentPane which is a Sprite that you can get the width and height from.

```
import mx_internal;
use namespace mx_internal;
var containerWidth : Number = container.mx_internal::contentPane.width;
var containerHeight : Number = container.mx_internal::contentPane.height;
```

Comment: Controls like Panels have a title and a status bar. The content area is not the whole control but only a part of it. I would like to have the boundaries of the content area only.

Comment: Not really an answer - but http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/IContainer.html#viewMetrics might help you.  That and headerHeight.